# Adding System.Drawing.Image to FixedDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, image, fixeddocument

I have 10 `System.Drawing.Image`. I need to add them to a `FixedDocument`. I tried the below code and the fixed document is procuded with all the 10 pages consists of only first image.

```
FixedDocument doc = new FixedDocument();
BitmapSource[] bmaps = new BitmapSource[10];
System.Drawing.Image[] drawingimages = //I have System.Drawing.Image in a array
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    Page currentPage = this.Pages[i];
    System.Drawing.Image im = drawingimages[i];
    im.Save(i + ".png");
    Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
    im.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
    ImageSource imgsource = decoder.Frames[0];

    bmaps[i] = imgsource as BitmapSource;
}
foreach (BitmapSource b in bmaps)
{
    PageContent page = new PageContent();
    FixedPage fixedPage = CreateOneFixedPage(b);
    ((IAddChild)page).AddChild(fixedPage);
    doc.Pages.Add(page);
}
```

Method for CreateOneFixedPage

```
private FixedPage CreateOneFixedPage(BitmapSource img)
{
    FixedPage f = new FixedPage();
    Image anImage = new Image();
    anImage.BeginInit();
    anImage.Source = img;
    anImage.EndInit();

    f.Children.Add(anImage);
    return f;
}
```

When I try saving the `System.Drawing.Image` to the local disk, all the 10 images are saved correctly.
What is the mistake in my code here?

Comment: What happens if you change the BitmapCacheOption to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` in BitmapDecoder.Create()?

Comment: And it is not necessary to call BeginInit() and EndInit() on an Image control.

Comment: @Clemens: Tried both,,,, but still problem persist

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not an answer to the question, but at least the code below shows a minimal working example. It loads all images from the Sample Pictures folder into a list of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` objects. Then it converts all list elements to `ImageSource` and adds each to a FixedDocment page.

Please not that it does not call `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` on the Image controls. Also it sets the PageContent's `Child` property, instead of calling `IAddChild.AddChild()`.

```
var bitmaps = new List<System.Drawing.Bitmap>();

foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
    @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures", "*.jpg"))
{
    bitmaps.Add(new System.Drawing.Bitmap(file));
}

foreach (var bitmap in bitmaps)
{
    ImageSource imageSource;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Position = 0;
        imageSource = BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
            BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }

    var page = new FixedPage();
    page.Children.Add(new Image { Source = imageSource });

    doc.Pages.Add(new PageContent { Child = page });
}
```

Comment: thanks @Clemens... this too fail to draw all the images. just draw only first page 10 times